How to Model the contribution of a continuos treatement on a limited dependet binary variable, with only records for positive outcome
I'm trying to estimate the causal contribution of a continuous treatment variable (number of marketing touchpoints) over a binary outcome variable (opportunity is generated or not). The challenge resides in that we know when an opportunity is generated (date) and collect all the marketing touchpoints in the previous 6 months if any (together with other covariates). However, there is no way to know when an opportunity failed to be generated, and so have negative outcome records. I've investigated the topic, but till this point, I'm still struggling to find any robust way to model the causal contribution of marketing, considering the data limitations.

Forget about causality, you can't even measure how a binary variable is correlated with another variable if there is no variance on that variable in your dataset. From what you describe it sounds like every single observation has the same value for your outcome variable, because you only collected data for people with a value of "1." Let's imagine two worlds, one where touchpoints is highly correlated with opportunities (people with more than X touchpoints are way way more likely to get opportunities than people with less than X), and a second world where the two things are totally uncorrelated. In both of those worlds you would see the exact same data that you have right now (everyone has opportunities, but some have different values of touchpoint). Since your data cannot distinguish between these two worlds (one where the two variables are highly correlated and one where they are not correlated at all) you cannot use these data to estimate that correlation.
Finally, since you mentioned causality, it's important to note that even if you did have data on cases with no opportunities and had a perfect measure of the correlation between these two variables, that doesn't mean you can estimate the causal relationship between them. Your ability to do that depends on how the independent variable works in the world (was it assigned randomly) how you collected the data, whether you can plausibly argue that you have controlled for all other confounding factors. Usually in statistics estimating a correlation is the easy part, but inferring causality is nightmarishly difficult. Here though, your problem is that you can't even estimate the correlation.

I can assume safely that all other major variables affecting the opportunities generations are measured (tickets of complaints of the accounts, tenure between the company and the account, ecc..) or at least indirectly taken into account. The only problem is, as discussed, that there is no express way to know where an opportunity failed to realize, as there is no data point collecting the failure on the sales side.  Wondering if any data generation approach could be employed to generate "negative" outcome records, or any approach in the field.

OR wondering if maybe the average timeline between a marketing touchpoint and the associated opportunity could used to define an "expected" time of conversion, and if after that average time no opportunities is generated, then considered a failure.

If you define "failure" in some way so that some people get zeros, then the correlational problem is solved, and you can estimate the correlation (but not necessarily the causal relationship) between success and other variables. Whether that definition of failure makes sense substantively is another (non statistical) question.

It's hard to see how that assumption can be safe. You're dealing with an observational study on humans. That precludes finding causality statistically. (You might find good evidence of causality in other ways).

It sounds like survival analysis might be helpful, if you have data on how long it was until the event occurred. You could then treat cases with no event as censored. But I'm not sure if you a) Have that data and b) Have enough uncensored data to make this reasonable.

@GrahamWright what about limited dependent variable models? I'm not an experte on the subject, but it seems there is a range of model able to deal with limited dependent variable values? At least to study association.

Here's the issue: if the question you are trying to answer is "did the treatment cause this thing to happen (vs not happen)?" then you are sunk, because the dependent variable has no variance to analyze. If you change your research question to something like "Among people who had the thing happen, did the treatment cause it to happen sooner (vs later)?" then you have a different dependent variable (time between treatment and event) that has variance and can be analyzed (e.g. by survival analysis or  various other methods). But that is a very different (and probably not as useful) question.

granted that without negative cases causation can't be. And assuming that we are not interested in timelines, as we know that a marketing touchpoint is not lasting more than bunch of weeks, however, studying association between positive outcomes and a specific variable should be possible. I'm still research the subject, but it seems that an approach could be modeling via Fitting truncated Poisson. By changing the design and studying if more opportunities are associated to higher numbers in the marketing covariate, theoretically a researcher should be able to validate if any association emerge
